# django put save button

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to change the data that is in this column from a form but I can't display the data and save them and also add a delete button. anyone have a solution.

models.py

```
class Employe(models.Model):
Matricule = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
Prenom = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
Nom = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
Tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
Adresse = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Courriel = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Horaire = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
Date_embauche = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
UtilisateurOSP = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
MotdepasseOSP = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
Anciennete = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
data_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Disciplinaire(models.Model):
employe = models.ForeignKey(Employe, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
Avis_verbal = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
Avis_ecrit = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
Avis_ecrit2 = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
Suspension = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
Fin_emploie = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
data_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class disciplinaireForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Disciplinaire
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def updateDisciplinaire(request, id):
emp = Disciplinaire.filter()
forms = disciplinaireForm(instance=emp)

if request.method == 'POST':
    forms = disciplinaireForm(request.POST, instance=emp)
    if forms.is_valid():
        forms.save()
        return redirect('/')

context = {'forms':forms}
return render(request, 'accounts/updateDisciplinaire.html', context)
```

page.html

```
      <th scope="col">Avis Verbal</th>
      <th scope="col">1er Avis Écrit</th>
      <th scope="col">2e Avis Écrit</th>
      <th scope="col">Suspension</th>
      <th scope="col">Fin d'emploi</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
     {% for j in disci %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{j.Avis_verbal}}</td>
        <td>{{j.Avis_ecrit}}</td>
        <td>{{j.Avis_ecrit2}}</td>
        <td>{{j.Suspension}}</td>
        <td>{{j.Fin_emploie}}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'updateDisciplinaire' j.id %}">Modifier</a>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

[data and button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJvEg.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jn1E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that in line 102 from your views.py you are trying to filter something. If you want to filter try:

```
emp_all = Disciplinaire.objects.filter(employe = id)
for emp in emp_all:
  print(emp.Matricule)
```

you need to put how to filter, by which field.
When you use filter it will get you a queryset, a list of records not just one single record, if you want a single record you can use get:

```
emp = Disciplinaire.objects.get(employe = id)
```

Comment: Not working i have AttributeError at /updateDisciplinaire/5/

'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta' /home//test1/test2/accounts/views.py, line 109, in updateDisciplinaire

        forms = disciplinaireForm(instance=emp)

Comment: Noted ! But now it said {Disciplinaire matching query does not exist.} ?

Comment: can you post the edited code?